# Failed to debug on PlatformIO with J-Link

Tags: gdb, stm32, platformio, segger-jlink

I'm trying to set up the debug environment of platformIO on vscode with J-Link to work with STM32f407ZG chip.

It can build & upload. But each time I tried to debug it throws me errors like this

```
warning: unrecognized item "timeout" in "qSupported" response
Ignoring packet error, continuing...
.pioinit:16: Error in sourced command file:
Remote replied unexpectedly to 'vMustReplyEmpty': timeout
```

My platformio.ini looks like this:

```
[env:black_f407zg]
platform = ststm32
board = black_f407zg
framework = stm32cube
debug_port = /dev/cu.usbmodem0000594258681

upload_protocol = jlink
debug_tool = jlink
```

Where exactly did I do wrong and what should I do next to make it work?

Comment: Try it without "debug_port".

Comment: It turns out it's an error with my openocd and config file.